# javascript: Behavior of variables in base object with inheritance

Tags: javascript

```
function Resource(){ 
    var id = '';

    this.getId = function(){
        return id;
    }

    this.setId = function(value){
        id = value;
    }
}

function Model(){ } 
Model.prototype = new Resource();
```

To test the above code, I have the following:

```
var m1 = new Model();
m1.setId("blah");
alert("m1 = " + m1.getId());

var m2 = new Model();
m2.setId("blahblah");
alert("m2 = " + m2.getId());

alert("m1 = " + m1.getId());
```

I would expect the following to be alerted: `m1 = blah, m2 = blahblah, m1 = blah`.

However, the following is being displayed: `m1 = blah, m2 = blahblah, m1 = blahblah`.

I have written the above code as an experiment so that I can begin to understand inheritance in JavaScript.  Perhaps my expectation of what should be displayed is due to my Java/C# background.  Clearly each new Model object created shares the same `id` variable defined in Resource.  Why is this?

How can I write this so that each new Model can have its own unique `id` (other than the obvious - defining in within Model)?

BTW, I have purposely definted id as `var id` rather than `this.id`, as I am looking for the private-variable behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prototype object is shared among all instances.

Because the `id` variable belongs to the `Resource` constructor, and because the `prototype` of `Model` is that single instance of `Resource`, all the `Model` instances are using that single instance, and therefore the same variable.

For each `Model` instance to have its own `id` variable, you'll need to create the `id` variable in the `Model` constructor, as well as the accessor methods.

```
function Model() {
    var id = '';

    this.getId = function(){
        return id;
    }

    this.setId = function(value){
        id = value;
    }
}
```

Another way to accomplish this is to invoke `Resource` using the `Model` instances as the context. This is done using `.call` or `.apply` like this:

```
function Model() {
    Resource.apply(this);
}
```

This will invoke the `Resource` function, which will create the `id` variable and its accessor methods, but the accessors will be assigned to the `Model` instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a scope issue, I specified that we're talking about `this.id` instead of just `id` in your get / set methods and it worked great:

```
this.getId = function(){
  return this.id;
}

this.setId = function(value){
  this.id = value;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thewebguy/zHDwC/

Comment: This exposes the `id`, which makes the local accessors unnecessary. The original code keeps the `id` protected by only allowing access through the accessor methods.